# how to use conditional get in restlet?

Tags: http, rest, get, restlet

I am currently designing an API using the restlet framework;
Can anyone please give me a clue on how to use conditional GET requests in RESTlet ?
what I mean is :
lets say I have the name and date of birth of many persons and I want to GET the name of persons that are older than 20 years, how could this be done ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at setting Etags in the http header? That's how you do a conditional get. You could access the etag fields in the ServerResource. It's more amenable to time based retrieval, in my opinion. What you want is not conditional get (i.e., get if modified) but rather get on "a condition" age>20 - you want to 'filter' the results returned. Implies an algorithmic aspect - implies URL parameter on age for a restful design :) So have something like mySite.com/Persons?age=>20 or something similar

Comment: @Nupul - that should have been an answer instead of a comment :). For conditional retrieval in REST, using a POST may be a better option.

Comment: @Prashant: Agreed. Realized after the fact :) Btw, anything with retrieval should be GET based, verbs match. Using POST is not RESTful, if you overload it with retrieval.